# Xcode 4 + Git - Useful for me?

Tags: xcode, git, homebrew

I've always searched for a decent visual diff tool for git diffs and merges and have never found one that is both great to use and stable... I've noticed that Xcode 4 has git built in now so was wondering how I could use both for my work.

So question 1)

I only do web dev, no OSX or iOS apps... but is there a way I can tap into Xcode to use their visual diff tool maybe?

question 2)

Without realising git was bundled, I installed Xcode (so Homebrew works) then installed git separately with "brew install git". Have I now doubled up and do I need to delete the one I installed with Homebrew?

question 3)

Would Xcode be any use to me for any reasons that I haven't noticed? would it be any use for project handling or anything?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Xcode ships with with its own three-way merge tool: /Developer/Applications/Utilities/FileMerge.app/  I haven't used Git in Xcode much but I bet that's the tool they use for doing diff/merging.

2) You doubled up but don't worry about it, many times people will install newer versions of OS X supplied tools (just make sure not to overwrite the one supplied by OS X.)

3) If you're not doing OS X/iOS development, I don't see Xcode being that good for you.  The editor in Xcode leaves a lot to be desired in my opinion.

My two cents.  :)

Comment: To add to #2 - `brew` only installs to `/usr/local/`, whereas XCode installs git to `/usr/bin` - both can co-exist, and brew has far newer versions (XCode 4.2 comes with 1.7.5.4, brew is 1.7.7.1).

Comment: That is correct...which is why I suggested never to overwrite the OS X supplied one because Git support in Xcode, and maybe Xcode itself, could stop working.  I know there was a hack to update Subversion in Xcode 3 but it was terrible.